# Generating Crops On tf.data.Dataset

Tags: tensorflow, dataset

so i want to do data augmentation on tf.data.Dataset and i want to generate 10-20 crops of those images and put them back inside of tf.data.Dataset.

transformation of dataset should look like this:

```
 [(image1; label), (image2; label)] -> [(crop1image1; label), (crop2image1;,label), ... (crop9image2; label), (crop10imag2; label)]
```

How is this possible to do?

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/crop_and_resize

Comment: @Lescurel but how to actually use that function multiple times on the tf.data.Dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`flat_map` method of `tf.data.Dataset` object can be used to do so:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Function to generate multiple crops for an image
def generate_crops(image, label):
    crops = []

    # Define the number of crops to generate for each image
    num_crops = tf.random.uniform([], minval=10, maxval=20, dtype=tf.int32)

    for _ in range(num_crops):
        # Randomly crop the image
        crop = tf.image.random_crop(image, size=[crop_height, crop_width, num_channels])
        
        crops.append((crop, label))

    return crops

# Define the size of the crops and number of channels
crop_height = 32
crop_width = 32
num_channels = 3

# Load your dataset here (e.g., using tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices())

# Apply data augmentation and generate multiple crops for each image
dataset = dataset.flat_map(generate_crops)

# Shuffle and batch the dataset as needed
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1000).batch(batch_size)

for batch in dataset:
    # Perform training steps here
    pass
```

Comment: it gave me this error "
TypeError: The `map_func` argument must return a `Dataset` object. Got <class 'tuple'>."

Comment: Fixed the problem thanks